# Elasticsearch timout doesn't work when do searching

Tags: elasticsearch

**Elasticsearch version** (`bin/elasticsearch --version`):5.2.2

**JVM version** (`java -version`): 1.8.0_121

**OS version** (`uname -a` if on a Unix-like system): opensuse

1. Do search with " curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty&timeout=1ms'  "
2. The part of response is : 
   {
   "took" : 5,
   "timed_out" : false,
   "_shards" : {
   "total" : 208,
   "successful" : 208,
   "failed" : 0
   },
   "hits" : {
   "total" : 104429,
   "max_score" : 1.0,
   "hits" :
   ...
3. The took time is 5ms, and timeout setting is 1ms. Why "timed_out" is false rather than true.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `timeout` is per searched shard (looks like 208 in your case), while the `took` is for the entire query. On a per shard level you are within the limit. The [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_search_options.html#_timeout_2) has some additional information on when you will hit `timed_out` and more caveats.

Try with a more expensive query (leading wildcard, fuzziness,...) — I guess then you should hit the (shard) limit.

Comment: Thanks for your help!